# Homomorphic Encryption and Semantic Security using Lattices?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, semantic-security

I've been reading Brakerski and Vaikuntanathan's "[Efficient Fully Homomorphic Encryption from (Standard) LWE](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2011/109/)" and I'm still digesting pieces at a time.

Under section 1.1, *"Re-Linearization: Somewhat Homomorphic Encryption without Ideals"*, they state they mask the plain text with noise. The noise is created with multiplications and additions of the plain text, and the result is cipher text:

> To encrypt a bit $m$ in $\{0, 1\}$ using secret key $\mathbf{s}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_q^n$, we choose a
>   random vector $\mathbf{a}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_q^n$ and a "noise" e and output the cipher text
>
> $c = (\mathbf{a},b = \langle \mathbf{a},\mathbf{s} \rangle + 2e + m)$
>
> The key observation in decryption is that the two “masks” – namely,
>   the secret mask $\langle \mathbf{a},\mathbf{s} \rangle$ and the "even mask" $2e$ – do not interfere with
>   each other. That is, one can decrypt this cipher text by annihilating
>   the two masks, one after the other: The decryption algorithm first
>   re-computes the mask $\langle \mathbf{a},\mathbf{s} \rangle$ and subtracts it from $b$, resulting in $2e + m \pmod{q}$.
>   Since $e \ll q$, then $2e + m \pmod{q} = 2e + m$.

How can this be semantically secure if the same mask $\langle \mathbf{a},\mathbf{s} \rangle$ is being used on messages? That is, two different encryptions of the same value (say "10") would produce the same cipher texts.

If I added two numbers (say "10" and "100"), wouldn't they need to be masked with the same $\langle \mathbf{a},\mathbf{s} \rangle$?
Or does this scheme require additional accounting somewhere to allow for different $\langle \mathbf{a},\mathbf{s} \rangle$ masks?

Comment: Is there a reason you chose that specific FHE cipher? I believe the standard LWE ciphers are much less efficient compared to the ring LWE ciphers.

Comment: mikeazo - I'm (slowly) working through the papers that describe practical system. Do you have a particular paper in mind?

Comment: In the abstract description of the scheme (which I assume you are referring to) the vector $\bf s$ is the secret key and the vector $\bf a$ is randomly chosen for $every$ encryption. If you look at the definition of the homomorphic addition (multiplication) you see that they use ciphertexts with respect to independently chosen $\bf a$ and $\bf a'$ for encryption of message $m$ and $m'$.

Comment: @DrLecter you mean that their breakthrough is that even you encrypt with different keys $k_1$ $k_2$ two plaintexts $p_1$, $p_2$ you can evaluate homomorphically an operation in their ciphertext space? But with which key you can decrypt it?

Comment: I cannot understand the purpose of the noise $e$ since it can be recovered applying  $\mod{2}$ to the ciphertext by everyone

Comment: @curious: Did I say anything about different keys?

Comment: @DrLecter " If you look at the definition of the homomorphic addition (multiplication) you see that they use ciphertexts with respect to independently chosen $a$ and $a′$ for encryption of message $m$ and $m′$ ": different a->different keys

Comment: The secret is $\bf s$ and they descibe a secret key variant (as far as I can see that)

Comment: @curious: How would you recover the message from the ciphertext when not knowing the secret $\bf s$. You would have to remove the inner product of $\bf a$ and $\bf s$.

Comment: @noloader the [BGV](http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/277) system is probably the most popular one and has a few optimizations ([1](http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/566) and [2](http://eprint.iacr.org/2012/099)) plus an [implementation](https://github.com/shaih/HElib).

Comment: @curious $e$ is the error part of learning with errors. There are some good tutorials out there on the LWE problem that might help. $a$ is like the random values used in Paillier or ElGamal. Those random values are not part of the secret key.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## The LWE assumption

I think we should start from the LWE assumption.
Let $n$ and $q$ be integers and let $\chi$ be a distribution over $\mathbb{Z}_q$. We often take $\chi$ as a Gaussian with small variance. (We take an error $e$ from this distribution $\chi$ and assume that $|e| \ll q$.)

The LWE assumption states that any efficient adversary cannot distinguish two oracles if a vector $\mathbf{s} \in \mathbb{Z}_q^n$ is chosen uniformly at random;

- one is the random oracle that returns $(\mathbf{a},b) \in \mathbb{Z}_q^n \times \mathbb{Z}_q$ chosen uniformly at random
- the other is the LWE oracle that returns $(\mathbf{a},b) \in \mathbb{Z}_q^n \times \mathbb{Z}_q$, where $\mathbf{a} \gets \mathbb{Z}_q^n$, $e \gets \chi$, and $b = \langle \mathbf{a},\mathbf{s} \rangle + 2e$.
  (Note: I replace $e$ with $2e$ from the correct definition. This is a minor problem.)

## The LWE-based Symmetric-key Encryption

Keeping the assumption in mind, we next review the symmetric-key encryption scheme appeared in your quotation.

- $\mathsf{Gen}(n,q)$: Choose $\mathbf{s} \in \mathbb{Z}_q^n$ uniformly at random. The secret key is $\mathbf{s}$.
- $\mathsf{Enc}(\mathbf{s},m \in \{0,1\})$:

  - Choose $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{Z}_q^n$ uniformly at random.
  - Take a sample $e$ from $\chi$.
  - Compute $b = \langle \mathbf{a},\mathbf{s} \rangle + 2e + m \in \mathbb{Z}_q$.
  - Output a ciphertext $c = (\mathbf{a},b)$.

This encryption scheme is apparently IND-CPA.
In the IND-CPA game, denoted by $G$, the adversary has an encryption oracle which has a secret key $\mathbf{s}$.
Let us replace the encryption oracle with the random oracle and call this game as $G'$.
It is easy to show that $G$ and $G'$ are indistinguishable under the LWE assumption.

## Answer

> How can this be semantically secure if the same mask $\langle \mathbf{a},\mathbf{s} \rangle$ is being used on messages? That is, two different encryptions of the same value (say "10") would produce the same cipher texts.
>   If I added two numbers (say "10" and "100"), wouldn't they need to be masked with the same $\langle \mathbf{a},\mathbf{s} \rangle$?
>   Or does this scheme require additional accounting somewhere to allow for different $\langle \mathbf{a},\mathbf{s} \rangle$ masks?

By this definition, two ciphertexts $c_1, c_2$ of plaintexts $m_1, m_2 \in \{0,1\}$ under the secret key $\mathbf{s}$ are written as

- $c_1 = (\mathbf{a}_1, b_1) = (\mathbf{a}_1,\langle \mathbf{a}_1,\mathbf{s} \rangle + 2e_1 + m_1)$ and
- $c_2 = (\mathbf{a}_2, b_2) = (\mathbf{a}_2, \langle \mathbf{a}_2,\mathbf{s} \rangle + 2e_2 + m_2)$.

If we can obtain two ciphertexts with the same mask, that is, two ciphertexts with the same randomness $\mathbf{a}$, they are not IND-CPA secure.
We have

- $c_1 = (\mathbf{a}, b_1) = (\mathbf{a},\langle \mathbf{a},\mathbf{s} \rangle + 2e_1 + m_1)$ and
- $c_2 = (\mathbf{a}, b_2) = (\mathbf{a}, \langle \mathbf{a},\mathbf{s} \rangle + 2e_2 + m_2)$.

It is easy to check the relation $m_1 - m_2 \bmod{2}$ by
the relation $b_1 - b_2 \equiv 2e_1 + m_1 - (2e_2 + m_2) \bmod{q}$.
Since $e_1, e_2, m_1, m_2$ is "small", $b_1 - b_2 \bmod{q} = 2(e_1 - e_2) + m_1 - m_2 \in [-q/2,q/2]$. Therefore, the difference $b_1 - b_2 \bmod{q}$ reveals the relation $m_1 - m_2 \bmod{2}$.

Finally, I mention that the scheme is additively homomorphic.
Suppose that we have two ciphertexts

- $c_1 = (\mathbf{a}_1, b_1) = (\mathbf{a}_1,\langle \mathbf{a}_1,\mathbf{s} \rangle + 2e_1 + m_1)$
- $c_2 = (\mathbf{a}_2, b_2) = (\mathbf{a}_2, \langle \mathbf{a}_2,\mathbf{s} \rangle + 2e_2 + m_2)$.

Consider $c_1 + c_2 \in \mathbb{Z}_q^n \times \mathbb{Z}_q$.

$c_1 + c_2 = (\mathbf{a}',b')$
$ = (\mathbf{a}_1 + \mathbf{a}_2, \langle \mathbf{a}_1 + \mathbf{a}_2, \mathbf{s} \rangle + 2(e_1 + e_2 + (m_1 + m_2 \mathbin{\mathrm{div}} 2)) + (m_1 + m_2 \bmod{2}))$.

Multiplication is tricky. I recommend to read the BGV paper, which employs "tensor" to make notation simpler than the BV paper.